# Nuget: Using Xamarin Forms and Google GCM packages together

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-messaging, nuget

I'm implementing push notifications on my Xamarin Forms Android app and currently installing required NuGet packages.

However, I've come across a package conflict issue: Xamarin Google Play Services (GCM) version 42.1001.0 and Xamarin Forms version 25.1.0 can't be installed on the same project, which seems to be due to the dependencies.

I read from the Xamarin forums https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57283/unable-to-find-a-version-of-xf-compatible-with, the packages require the exact version for their dependencies, which is unfortunate because there are some overlapping dependency packages.

Is there a way around this?

The installation log when installing Xamarin Forms then Google Play Services:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (= 42.1001.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 42.1001.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Build.Download (≥ 0.4.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (≥ 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks (= 42.1001.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid (= 42.1001.0)'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.2'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Build.Download 0.4.2'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 25.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 25.1.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI 25.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI 25.1.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 25.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 25.1.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat 25.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat 25.1.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 25.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 25.1.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.1.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 42.1001.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 42.1001.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks 42.1001.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks 42.1001.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 42.1001.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 42.1001.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid 42.1001.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid 42.1001.0'.
Installing 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm 42.1001.0'.
Successfully installed 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm 42.1001.0'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0' to 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.1.0' failed. Unable to find versions of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' that are compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.1.0'
```

The installation log when Google Play Services *then* Xamarin Forms:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (≥ 23.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Build.Download (≥ 0.4.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat (= 25.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (≥ 23.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)'.
Already referencing a newer version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4'.
```

P.S. It's my first question post, so let me know if I need more explanations or details. :)

Comment: What `Xamarin.Android` framework version are you targeting?

Comment: Compilation (Target Framework) is set to `Use Latest Platform (Android 7.1 (Nougat))` and Target Android version is set to `Use Compile using SDK version`

Comment: Which `Xamarin.Forms` version are you using?

Comment: Version 2.3.4.224 (just realised the question had a completely wrong version number, sorry about that)

Comment: I'm trying to install `Xamarin Google Play Services - GCM` version 42.1001.0

Answer (score 0):

I just added `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm` v42.1001.0 to a `monoandroid71` targeted w/ the latest `Xamarin.Forms`(v2.3.4.231) and ended up with a `package.config` of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.3.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.4" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.231" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
</packages>
```

I stripped the packages and refs and tried it with `Xamarin.Forms` v2.3.4.224 and ended up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.1.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Build.Download" version="0.4.4" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.224" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Iid" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks" version="42.1001.0" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Hmm, I completely uninstalled `Xamarin.Forms` v.2.3.4.224 and installed v.2.3.4.231 and for some reason, the `packages.config` file has different version numbers than yours for the dependency packages.

Comment: For example, the first package is version 23.3.0 compared to your version which is 25.1.0

`<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid71" />`

Comment: @NickToh Perform a package update on the entire project

Comment: Yes, managed to install `Xamarin Google Play Services (GCM)`! :D Thanks so much for help, saved me hours of banging my head on the computer and restarting 100s of times!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that's having this same issue, try updating all your packages from the project level. If you get errors, try manually updating each package, run Visual Studio as admin and retrying several times (believe it or not, there was a pesky package that updated after trying to do so 4 times!).